# How to get project to use JRuby instead of Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, jruby

I'm trying to stand up a JRuby/Ruby-on-Rails environment on a Windows VM. As a result, I installed Ruby, Rails and the items from the [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en) download. I then installed [JRuby](http://www.jruby.org/download). Everything installed and I see both when I do `jruby -v` and `ruby -v`.

How do I get my Rails project to recognize JRuby instead of Ruby? Can I achieve this without installing RVM? Should I just install RVM on the Windows VM (which I was trying to avoid, but, maybe I shouldn't)? Do I just put a line in the `Gemfile`?

(My very limited experience with JRuby/Ruby-on-Rails is with using RVM on a Unix environment.)

Here's my output when I do a `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.9
 - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-09-25 patchlevel 392) [java]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/gems/shared
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/jruby-1.7.16/bin/jruby.exe
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-1.7.16/bin
 - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/user/.gem/specs
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
   - ruby
   - universal-java-1.7
 - GEM PATHS:
    - C:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/gems/shared
    - C:/Users/user/.gem/jruby/1.9
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
    - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
    - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
 - SHELL PATH:
    - C:\Windows\system32
    - C:\Windows
    - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    - c:\jruby-1.7.16\bin
    - C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd
    - C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin
    - C:\Program Files\jruby-1.7.16\bin
```

Comment: What does `gem env` output? Add that to your question by editing, and appending the output.

Comment: @theTinMan I added the output of gem env per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is a gem and it's installed within a Ruby installation by Rubygems, which is part of a Ruby distribution. Your path setting are set in the way, that the `gem` command is coming from Ruby and not from JRuby. You can remove all Ruby commands temporarily from your path, and as long as JRuby's commands are on the path it will automatically pick those.

By doing `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` you then will install Rails and all the project dependencies with JRuby.

However, that's what version managers actually do. They just switch the path settings properly. Using them simplifies the configuration of an development environment a lot. And, for Windows there is [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) (RVM works only on Unix systems).

Comment: For accuracy, RVM runs on *nix (Unix and Linux variants, including Mac OS).

Comment: Pik seems to be outdated. It installed old ruby & jruby versions. I get the impression that no one is maintaining it.

Comment: Hmm. Last commit 2 years ago. That's sad. And unfortunately a pretty common experience with ruby and windows. Actualy your gem env says that is using jruby because it is on the path before ruby.

Comment: :) Sad indeed. I'll check out uru though. I installed jruby and I made sure it is definitely on the PATH before ruby. Thanks for your help.