# Ruby on Rails Extremely Slow to Load Pages and Once Load have to Refresh for Buttons to Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a cinema system in Ruby on Rails and I BIG problem I am having is that the pages take ages to load, and when they do load the buttons don't work so I have to refresh the page.

I don't know why it does it, but I have a huge CSS, and because its a cinema site I have film images and film trailers; in total the directory is 359MB, with the videos folder (in the public folder) being 266MB.

When I first run the server using `rails s` I get this output:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

I am precompiling the videos and images in `config/intitializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['public/videos']
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['app/assets/images']
```

I am using Firefox (but its the same on all browsers) and Windows 7.

Can someone please advise me on how to improve this issue.

Comment: The WEBrick server is not recommended to run in production. Have you every tested the performance with a "real" application server (passenger, unicorn, puma)?

Comment: Sorry for sounding thick, but how would I do that?

Comment: Let me rephrase: Do you have a plan how to deploy your application to the public? Perhaps Heroku or a server in the Amazon cloud?

Comment: No. This is part of a project and would not be used by the public

Comment: Start by narrowing down the problem: is it that the view renders slowly, lots of database queries, client side performance problems , an inefficient algorithm in one of your models, something else?

Comment: I think its likely to be slow rendering and client side performance

Answer (score 1):

I think

**Firstly** its Windows. Ruby is slow in windows, therby rails is slow.

**Secondly** try `puma`

**Thirdly** altough I can't see what the queries are, but I feel you should preload the whatever association you have, if possible, which would reduce the number of queries.

**Fourthly**, you could run linux on a VM and run rails on it.

**Lastly** I haven't tried this, see if it is possible to run rails with `jRuby`. it supports multi-threading and should be faster.

Here is a tutorial on integration of Jruby with existing rails proj..

[From Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby) and [From other resource](http://rockyj.in/2012/09/09/rails_on_ruby_jruby_a_performance_comparison.html), :) , You can skip the pg sql part and replace the pgsql sql driver with mysqll jdbc driver..

Comment: I am trying the `puma gem` now, how would I would preload the queries and run rails with `jRuby`? Using Linux isn't really an option unfortuneately

Comment: well , I am looking into the jRuby thing, with puma you can setup number of workers, I have also heard that Passenger is also good, but I haven't tried it .. as to how to preload associations, I can give you an example,..supposing user has many comments, you can @user.includes(:comments).each do || in you view ..

Comment: Ok, I am trying to install puma but get the error: `Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.` and I think I already have associations like those

Comment: I have posted two links on using jruby with rails.. tell us how the performace .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151812

Comment: skip the rvm part ... see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261334 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216128/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75007/discussion-between-benjs-1-and-argentum47).